# Problem in installing Ubuntu 16.04.1 using virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, architecture

I want to install the Ubuntu using the Virtual box. I am following the steps shown on this forum

When I click New on Virtual box. It only gives me an option for Ubuntu 32 bit, not 64 bit, Why is it so?

I have downloaded the virtual box VirtualBox 5.1.8 for Windows hosts  x86/amd64
Ubuntu from official site is ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64

With choosing 32 bit and setting Ram of 1 Gb and 16 GB Hardisk.

I am getting this error:

```
This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detectedd an i686 CPU
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU
```

Comment: @JonasCz I have updated my question can you please now

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to disable the Hyper-V platform. My English level is not good enough to explain in detail how to do it, but look at the Windows features and you will find the option

Comment: is this what you are saying? [link](http://www.poweronplatforms.com/enable-disable-hyper-v-windows-10-8/)

Comment: Yes  
That is what you have to do

Comment: I have Windows 7 Enterprise and there is no Hyper-V platform